# Unable to upload images in the wordpress media

Tags: php, wordpress

In my site till previous month i am able to upload images in the post->media
now it says some error like

> Unable to create directory
>   /var/www/vhosts/modeling.com/httpdocs/wp-content/uploads/2012/03. Is
>   its parent directory writable by the server?

I checked from root folder all forder has a write permission

In coding part

> $stat = stat( dirname( $new_file ));
>   $perms = $stat['mode'] &
>   0000666;  @ chmod( $new_file, $perms );

i am using above to give permission for a newly created folder.Newly created folder also have 777 permission but i am unable to upload images within the folder.I spend more than a day still i am facing the same issue please guide me

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem couple of weeks back - try turning php's `safe_mode` off. should work like a charm after that...

Comment: Thank you for comments how to i change the mode could you explain please

Comment: either do this in the php.ini or via the admin panel for you v-server

Comment: Yes i already checked in the adminpanel -> setting -> media there Store uploads in this folder field have wp-content/uploads .

Comment: not in the admin panel of WP but in the admin panel of your server.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple solution for this is

Login to your wordpress admin Go to Setting->media
You will see the path in a text field with a label "Store uploads in this folder".
In your case it will be  /var/www/vhosts/modeling.com/httpdocs/wp-content/uploads/
Just remove the slash in the front and make it like 
var/www/vhosts/modeling.com/httpdocs/wp-content/uploads/

Save the settings and you will be able to upload images.